# cygwin emacs w32 does not ask to save edited files when shutting down windows

Tags: cygwin

I am running cyginw's native w32 emacs program on Windows 7.  If I edit a file in emacs, and don't save changes, when I shut down Windows, the emacs session is killed without asking to save edited files.  Is there a fix for this?  I realize I can manually quit emacs before shutting down, but it would be better to not have to think about this.

Comment: Sounds like a bug, you might be best to try reporting it using M-x report-emacs-bug.